# How to user unloadStyleDeclarations?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a flex4 applciation (mx+spark). When I use:

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.styleManager.loadStyleDeclarations(skinName, true);
```

This works fine: new style is applied.

The trouble is when I apply a new style, it mixes both: this happens because I need to Unload style first.

I try to unload it with:

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.styleManager.unloadStyleDeclarations("style/normal.swf",false);
```

And I always got an error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: La property 0 cannot be found on Number 
  and there is no default value.
    at normal/unloadOverrides()[null/normal-generated.as:721]
    at normal/unload()[null/normal-generated.as:676]
```

Any idea on how to load/unload swf css in Flex4?

Answer (score 0):

The styles will be updated the next time one of the following methods is called with the update property set to true:

```
clearStyleDeclaration()

loadStyleDeclarations()

setStyleDeclaration()

unloadStyleDeclarations()
```

Typically, if you call the one of these methods multiple times, you set this property to true only on the last call, so that Flex does not call the `styleChanged()` method multiple times.

More information [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/styles/IStyleManager.html#setStyleDeclaration%28%29).